# equals() and hashCode() override in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is there any way to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for types from `*-items.xml` ? For example:

```
 <itemtype code="FaqParagraph" extends="GenericItem" autocreate="true" generate="true"
                  jaloclass="com.training.core.jalo.FaqParagraph">
            <deployment table="FaqParagraph" typecode="20004"/>
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="code" type="java.lang.String">
                    <modifiers initial="true" write="false" optional="false"/>
                    <persistence type="property"/>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
 </itemtype>
```

Is there any way to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` for `FaqParagraphModel` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about generated **Model instances, there is no possibility to have a custom implementation for `hashCode` and `equals`. Please note that the "generated" implementation considers two instances as equals if they have the same `PK` and are in the same `tenant`.

Comment: Yes, it was about the generated model instances. I know they're *equal* (please note the italic font) if they have the same PK, but I was wondering why a `Set<FaqParagraphModel>` works correctly if the `equals()` and `hashCode()` aren't overridden. Thank you for your answer, maybe you can help me with this question too :)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `equals()` "works correctly"? Do you mean set elements are considered equal if they have the same `code` attribute?

Comment: I mean that the `Set` collection in order to work correctly on objects, they need to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods, but still, the generated model doesn't override them and the `Set<FaqParagraphModel>` works as expected.

Comment: In java, every instance of every class has an implementation of equals and hashcode. The basic implementation (defined in `Object` class) considers two objects equal if they are exactly the same (i.e: the two variables are assigned to the same object). For Hybris entities, the implementation is in AbstractItem, it makes equality over the PK.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand now. Thank you very much ! :)